# How to get pixels of ONLY last ROW of an image and display it in picture box. C#

Tags: c#

I have a question that how can we get pixels of only last row of an image and display that row in a picturebox of C# application.

Comment: This may be one of the rare cases when GetPixel/SetPixel is not too slow.. But there is an overload of DrawImage the takes two rectangles, which will still  probably be faster..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest (but also fastest) way I see is to use the following [Bitmap Constructor (Int32, Int32, Int32, PixelFormat, IntPtr)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14(v=vs.110).aspx) overload in combination with [Bitmap.LockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx) / [Bitmap.UnlockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.unlockbits(v=vs.110).aspx) like this

```
static Bitmap GetLastRow(Bitmap source)
{
    var data = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, source.Height - 1, source.Width, 1), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, source.PixelFormat);
    try { return new Bitmap(data.Width, data.Height, data.Stride, data.PixelFormat, data.Scan0); }
    finally { source.UnlockBits(data); }
}
```

In general you can use this code to crop any rectangular part of a bitmap by just changing the `new Rectangle(...)` part.

**Update:** It turns out that there is even a predefined method -  [Bitmap.Clone(Rectangle, PixelFormat)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944(v=vs.110).aspx), so the code could be simply

```
Bitmap source = ...;
var lastRow = source.Clone(new Rectangle(0, source.Height - 1, source.Width, 1), source.PixelFormat);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Bitmap LastRow(Bitmap source)
{
   int y = source.Height - 1;
   Bitmap newSource = new Bitmap(source.Width, 1);
   for (int x = 0; x < source.Width; x++)
   {
       NewSource.SetPixel(x, y, Source.GetPixel(x, y));
   }
   return newSource;
}
```

**Sample usage:**

```
pictureBox1.Image = LastRow(yourImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the fastest way, but should work:

```
        Bitmap image1 = new Bitmap(@"picture.bmp");
        Bitmap image2 = new Bitmap(image1.Width, 1, image1.PixelFormat);
        for (int i = 0; i < image1.Width; i++)
        {
            image2.SetPixel(i, 0, image1.GetPixel(i, image1.Height - 1));
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = image2;
```